# Swift - Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got this error, but I'm trying to get a `String` from a `Dictionary`. This is my code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            let dictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

            if let username = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                cell.name.text = username
            }

            if let userlogin = dictionary["login"] as? String {
                cell.login.text = userlogin
            }

        })
```

In my **Firebase Database** *"name"* and *"login"* are both Strings. I cannot understand what's the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Issue regards snapshot cast to NSDictionary. Check snaphsot content while debugging

Comment: `snapshotvalue` is string and you are trying to convert that value to dictionary.

Comment: @lubilis, I needed to use if let construction. Thank you very much! You saved me!

Comment: Welcome mate:) Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue regards snapshot cast to NSDictionary. Since snapshot value is a String.
Try this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            if let username = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                cell.name.text = username
            }

            if let userlogin = dictionary["login"] as? String {
                cell.login.text = userlogin
            }
        }
    })
```