# Firebase iOS Swift retrive list of favourites with data from other node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Pictures
-pictureID
-- name
-- date

Like
-pictureID
-- userID: true
-- userID: true

likePerUser
-userID
--pictureID: true
--pictureID: true

Users
-userID
-- name
-- lastname
```

I would like to retrieve all picture that current user has liked.

I did:

```
          ref.child("likePerUser").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

      for item1 in snap.children{

      let firstItem1 = (snap: item1 as! FIRDataSnapshot)
          print("key favourites\(firstItem1.key)")

           let firstId = firstItem1.key


   self.ref.child("pictures").child(firstId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in



    for item in snapshot.children{

      let firstItem = (snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
      print("key pictures \(firstItem.key)")
               let dict = firstItem.value as! [String: Any
                   let name = dict["name"] as! String 
 print(name)

    }
```

Even, If it seems that firstId has the right value each time, 
I always get an error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x110dae5b8) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x110daf288).

Please help....

Comment: if you wanna get some help, fix your code and tell us where the error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved doing this:

```swift
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            if let name = dictionary["nome"] as? String {
                print(name)
            }
}
```

This questions helped me: [Swift - Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831641/swift-could-not-cast-value-of-type-nscfstring-to-nsdictionary)

Also i didn't need to iterate once more.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dict = firstItem.value as! [String: Any
```

Here is where you attempt to cast a value as a dictionary. It's unclear whether the value is a dictionary based upon the model of the database you've shared. But there's a good chance that if you print `firstItem.value.debugDescription`, you will see that the value it isn't a dictionary object.

Comment: Thnx for the answer, if i print what you suggested me i get:

optional (name)
optional (date)

for every picture i liked so i see it's not a dictionary, but how can i access those value if i can't iterate dictionary?

Comment: It would help me if you updated your question to show a more complete model of your database.  For example, your model of the database doesn't show a child called "favperuser", but you use one in your code. In any event, check your code's case and spelling to make sure it exactly matches the name of the path in your database.